# Google In-App Product Currency Change

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing, in-app

Guys I have a US Google developer account. Now I want to add in-app products in that account. While setting the price of the product is it possible to set the currency other than US dollars ?like in INR (Indian rupees). I can see its showing the current conversion rate in INR but I don't want it to be dollar dependent.

Do I would have to change the account location. ? 
can I even do that ? 
I just want it to be INR dependent and not US dollar dependent.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an app is uploaded to Google Play, you will be asked to set a default price for the app in your home currency. This price will be used for all countries/regions which you do not manually override. **Additionally, you can set a price for each app separately in individual currency per country.** The prices you set in one currency are completely independent of prices in other currencies.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412

Comment: How do i change my default currency? Local currency in my country is really volatile, I would like to use US currency instead. How do i change that? I don't want to maintain it every week.